# using SimpleAudioEngine with avaudioRecorder

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine

I know i cant use the `SimpleAudioEngine` before the `avaudioRecorder` because it sets the session to play and not record.

If i record with the recorder then play with :

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]  playEffect:soundFilePath pitch:2.0f pan:0.0f gain:1.0f];
```

it works great, but if then i am trying to record again, its not .

i have to play with the  `SimpleAudioEngine` , and i am looking for a way to let it record again after i play.

i have tried after playing to do :

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```

with no success .

any help ?

thanks.

Comment: you want something like talking tom?